# Unable to use publickey authentication on Win32 Open SSH server

Tags: windows, openssh, google-cloud-platform

I have been using pubkey auth for SSH on Linux for years, and now I am trying to get it working on [the Win32 port](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) on a Windows 2016 server. So far unsuccessfully. I have read the help file for [sshd_config](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/sshd_config), which says to put the credentials in `<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys`, just like in a normal Linux setup. I have also verified that it is only readable by the user and the admin groups by looking at the ACLs. Additionally, I ready that I could put my client public key in `%programdata%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys`, so I did that, as well. Still, no go. I looked in the Event Viewer for any special signs of what is going on, but could not see anything special pointing to public key authentication. Just a bunch of logon attempts from the usual hacker crowd.

You can see the client trying to supply the server with my RSA keys and that the server accepts `publickey` as a logon method:

```
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:cicl5t/5mDmIocrkDopK2C6Rf9OvT7FhKAh9GEMPFd8 myuser@ubuntu
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
```

You see it trying two keys, the default one `67hw/H...` and another one that is for GCE, `cicl5t...`. The server logs in Windows show that they are both being denied:

```
sshd: Failed publickey for myuser from 77.88.92.5 port 57621 ssh2: RSA SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U
sshd: Failed publickey for myuser from 77.88.92.5 port 57621 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cicl5t/5mDmIocrkDopK2C6Rf9OvT7FhKAh9GEMPFd8
```

The fingerprint is valid:

```
$  ssh-keygen -l -E sha256 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
2048 SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U myuser@i9-ACME (RSA)
```

If you look at the log dump from the server at the bottom, you can see it never even tries to open the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Instead it just looks at `\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`. Yet, even though I have added the key there, it *still* refuses to log me in.

You can also see that I have added it correctly on the Windows server side, as the fingerprint is the same:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\.ssh> ssh-keygen -l -f .\authorized_keys
2048 SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U i9-ACME (RSA)
```

I have also followed instructions for [file settings](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Security-protection-of-various-files-in-Win32-OpenSSH), avoiding unnecessarily wide read rights:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\.ssh> icacls .\authorized_keys /inheritance:r
processed file: .\authorized_keys
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

PS C:\Users\myuser\.ssh> icacls.exe .\authorized_keys
.\authorized_keys NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(N)
                  BUILTIN\Administrators:(N)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Still no go. I have also restarted the OpenSSH services after the changes.

**Full server logs from `sshd -dd`:**

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from 77.88.92.5 port 52794 on 10.166.0.3 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,Open
SSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 1900
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-n
istp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-
group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@o
penssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@o
penssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preaut
h]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preaut
h]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-n
istp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-
group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha
2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh
.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@o
penssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@o
penssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preaut
h]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preaut
h]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 294
debug1: user myuser matched group list administrators at line 88
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for myuser [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user myuser querying public key rsa-sha2-512 AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCtB10ag2fipH
7Cnls3gZvl5eBJx0OvQaLu7hndL5sif3m4CTGmrN/MuP0lei0Rt23cBy5Ey2DqAjmizCAhdc3jSQm0pXisKG92Juo2HxiJw+eMUucoPhjbEy35sKKrru2//5
uPpK5IEeVEve3bIXCAQUQgyOESmHBgXmKSCz0jQXEvcV8GxxkdXK7/UQVSe5wtxzPHOoP+yeRdNGfMdl1SeXwUCEXwexAn7YM8ZlISufuxXMInpBMrxVXLAi
h0ZG2WGD2BAJZcwXmMjLPPVP+bjHXnQkiqk5oDeP3ewPorrvxbOeOcqk0b1qrAQYSXHqXv6lENfWIceIz1EsZlRsIV [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U [preauth]
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
Authentication refused.
Failed publickey for myuser from 77.88.92.5 port 52794 ssh2: RSA SHA256:67hw/H9QTbRYNl1n/xxhbB76lPm88yhyuVfIjxIWE1U
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user myuser querying public key rsa-sha2-512 AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDCaISFI0hCDM
K5SIqIBlsboBQTBCoW98bvjUjoCDn9S4kXSOtVvwNeXc/Kb+9lXqKR8CbtYgOZySPqI+5VADdAIcfot2S65Fq5qOQ1IH7Uo29nzvhyjfRbckAs3gaTF6uzxE
A0THqyAZ1oGIyK3vDI8W/Ofczi08oIYWpMmWA8dQNQuKRujloDuFElpjZEjbEyfkn/e7iSm1VxZ8aLEw7M3/BsJLmtwxa+tYyTAfKx63NRFbSWf873GLOyAK
CnE5ls27ftlTjDJMISI3RZd1KMdyg+6KAwN7YsCTwJXarNXr9v2GcY8lrpC7dQ/lGK1nBsPa0kOSYKQzJ0LIDxfOan [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:cicl5t/5mDmIocrkDopK2C6Rf9OvT7FhKAh9GEMPFd8 [preauth]
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
Authentication refused.
Failed publickey for myuser from 77.88.92.5 port 52794 ssh2: RSA SHA256:cicl5t/5mDmIocrkDopK2C6Rf9OvT7FhKAh9GEMPFd8
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 3 failures 2 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=myuser devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
```

**Output from `net user myuser`**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> net user myuser
User name                    myuser
Full Name                    myuser
Comment
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            12/20/2019 9:13:31 AM
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          12/20/2019 9:13:31 AM
Password required            Yes
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   4/6/2020 3:09:27 PM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators
Global Group memberships     *None
The command completed successfully.

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Did you check server log file? `C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs\sshd.log`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That directory was empty.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Win32 OpenSSH logs using the Windows Event Log system by default, so no wonder :-) You can see log output from it above. It refuses both keys.

Comment: _(Just a general FYI, Win32-OpenSSH is far enough along now that it almost exactly mirrors the functionality of the Linux version it's being ported from)_  I'm assuming you're trying to SSH into a Windows system running a Win32-OpenSSH server?  Were the two required Powershell scripts for correctly setting permissions run when Win32-OpenSSH was installed?  Whenever I've had this issue, it always comes down to either something is wrong with the `authorized_keys` file (`echo` the key into `authorized_keys`), a configuration issue in `sshd_config`, or incorrectly configured local user on Windows.

Comment: @JW0914 I reinstalled everything from scratch, just to see, but that made no difference. What did make a difference was throwing on a _third_ debug flag to troubleshoot this. That did in fact point to wrong permissions on a file no one mentioned: `administrators_authorized_keys`. If you look at the output, `sshd` does not even bother looking at `.ssh/authorized_keys` for me, probably because it treats admins differently.

Comment: @oligofren Is your user only a member of `Administrators` and not `Users` as well?

Comment: @JW0914 That's right. Not that I tried to _not_ mention that (I honestly did not know): it's just the default setting when adding a user using the Windows images in Google Compute Engine. I have added the output from `net user myuser` to show the gruops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a THIRD `-d` to the sshd config helped me see the problem:

```
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: Bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user: NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users (S-1-5-11) on file C:/Prog
ramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys.
Authentication refused.
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
```

1. For some reason `authorized_keys` is not used for administrator users. Not sure why.
2. The key needs to be present in `administrators_authorized_keys`.
3. The same file restrictions present on `authorized_keys` applies to `administrators_authorized_keys`.

`debug1` and `debug2` did not show the problem, but `debug3` did: it was the permission for my own user to see the contents of `administrators_authorized_keys` that kept messing this up. After removing that, I could finally log in.

I have yet to find a source that explains `administrators_authorized_keys` though ... [This issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1324) is the best so far.

Comment: I would open an issue on Win32-OpenSSH's GitHub, as they need to incorporate the permissions check of `%ProgramData%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` into `%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSH\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1`, which appears to have been an oversight since the script checks `%UserProfile%\.ssh\authorized_keys`.  Issue [Is administrators_authorized_keys a security problem](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1324) is also a decent read, especially [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1324#issuecomment-521247874) third comment from the bottom.

Comment: @JW0914 Done. https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1582